# I could use some direction or help to see if I am on the right path for this problem.

Tags: piecewise-continuity, steady-state, partial-differential-equations

> The problem is to solve the PDE:
>   $$
> \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^{2}}
>  - \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(K(x)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)
> $$
>   subject to the following boundary conditions:
>   $$
> \begin{split}
> u(0,t) &= 1, \\
> u(1,t) &= 0,  \\
> u(x,0) &= u_t(x,0) &=0
> \end{split}
> $$
>   with
>   $$
> K(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> 1,& 0 \lt x \lt 1/2 \\
> 2,& 1/2 \lt x \lt 1
> \end{cases}
> $$

So far I have solved the steady state solution and got:
$$
u_{ss}(x)=
\begin{cases}
-\frac{4x}{3} + 1,   & 0   < x < 1/2 \\
-\frac{2x}{3} + 2/3, & 1/2 < x < 1
\end{cases}
$$
But this is where I get stuck, I know that I need to solve for $$v(x,t) = u(x,t) - u_{ss}(x)$$The piece wise is throwing me off here, and I know that once I have $v(x,t)$ I will likely sovle it through separation of variables. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Your PDE does not have a right hand side, so is not an E.  Should the first line be equal to $0$?

Comment: @RossMillikan Yeah, I believe so I was confused about that also the problem itself does not have a RHS. In solving for the steady state I set $ \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = 0$